# Adding a secondary axis in ggplot corresponding to date when plotting Latitude and Longitude of an individual

Tags: r

I have data containing Latitude and Longitude of an individual. An example of a subset of my data can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NWYr8GOwf8WFqfeFf7mUPU2Jt5rkCUYs/view?usp=share_link

The data includes the Latitude and Longitude of locations (approx. every three hours depending on error in fix rates) over a year. There are multiple points per day for the individual. There is also a column corresponding to the elevation of that location.

I am trying to plot the Longitude and Latitude by time (either month or date). So for I have the following code to create this plot:

```
#read data and format columns;
##month and day as factor for ease of graphing but might need to change to continuous
d<-read.csv("Sample_Data.csv") %>% 
  mutate(Month=as.factor(Month), ##creates month as factor
         Day=as.factor(Day))%>%##create day as factor 
  arrange(DateTime)##arrange dates 

##Plot lat and long- connected by path of travel 
trial1<-ggplot(data=d,aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude))+
  geom_path()+
  geom_point(size=0.5)+
  coord_cartesian()+
  theme_bw()
```

Which results in the following figure:
[image: LatLongPlot]

What I would like to do is add a second axis corresponding to Date or month (pulled from these respective columns in my dataframe), depending on which subsets I will be working with. Essentially I want to create the same figure as above but have the Date (month) as a secondary x-axis so I can visualize paths on a temporal scale as well. I have been using ggplot and am aware I can add a secondary axis through this code, with will duplicate my longitude axis:

```
Trial1+scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = (~.))
```

There are lots of resources out there for adding secondary axes, as well as the facet_wrap() feature, however I would like one figure that shows both the temporal and spatial aspects of my data.

Is there a way that I can tell the secondary axis to pull data from the Month Column of my dataset and plot the Lat and Long versus the Month using ggplot?

I am also willing to look into other option in various packages, but want to try and avoid needing to create different data types (move objects for example, or trajectories) as I will need to work further with my data outside of these movement specific packages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand how such an axis would work. You may arrive at the same longitude value on very different days. How would you label the axis in that case? The time component wouldn't necessarily increase along an axis over time. This is not clear what you expect the output to look like exactly.

Comment: Adding secondary x axis of date to the current x-axis of longitude is possible. But what would be the y-axis against second x-axis in your new graph, the current y-axis, latitude?